# Perché si dice "andare a genio"?

Tags: idioms, etymology

Nel racconto *I barattoli* di Marisa Madieri ho letto:

> "La Fiorella gli *andava a genio* perché era rispettosa e aveva imparato a non toccare mai le sue cose senza il suo permesso."

Nel [Dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/G/genio.shtml#1) ho trovato che "andare a genio" significa

> piacere, essere gradito, attirare, invogliare; anche risultare congeniale.

Sono curiosa di sapere quale sia l'origine di questa espressione. Mi potreste dire qualcosa al riguardo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Secondo la Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/genio1/), "genio" significa, tra l'altro, "carattere, indole, gusto", da cui l'espressione "a genio" e altre:

> secondare il proprio g., il g. di altri; non è cosa conforme al mio
>   g.; persona o cosa di mio, tuo g., ecc., che s’accorda con l’indole e
>   con le opinioni nostre o d’altri: è un lavoro di mio g.; mi pare che
>   non sono riuscito di suo g.; finalmente avete trovato un’occupazione
>   di vostro g. (anche iron.); dare nel g. a qualcuno, andargli a g.,
>   incontrarne il g., piacergli, riuscirgli simpatico, impressionarlo
>   favorevolmente: la tua proposta non mi va a g.; è un giovanotto che
>   incontra poco il mio g.; fare una cosa di g., con g., volentieri, con
>   piacere, con soddisfazione, in quanto conforme alla propria indole.

Direi comunque che, a parte l'espressione "(non) andare a genio", le altre sono antiquate (e anche "andare a genio" non si usa moltissimo).