# "Sono curioso/a di sapere" + indicativo o congiuntivo?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

Ho avuto questo dubbio quando ho scritto [questa mia domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3849/707). Infatti, prima ho scritto "sono curiosa di sapere quale è l'origine", ma poi ho modificato il testo e finalmente ho messo "sono curiosa di sapere quale sia l'origine". Mi potreste dire se si dovrebbe usare l'indicativo o il congiuntivo in questo costrutto?

Comment: Se ne parla qui: https://books.google.es/books?id=wo4gDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT70&lpg=PT70&dq=interrogativa+indiretta+congiuntivo&source=bl&ots=c02lsXmwXg&sig=gZM70cfEBS1mw1hxze988FEEPqQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFoovQ4rzYAhUDbhQKHTvLAmw4ChDoAQgdMAc#v=onepage&q=interrogativa%20indiretta%20congiuntivo&f=false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

È una interrogativa indiretta totale e sono corrette entrambe: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/interrogative-indirette_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/

In particolare:

"Le interrogative indirette possono avere il verbo all’indicativo, come in (62), (63) e (64); al congiuntivo, come in (65) e (66); al condizionale, come in (67), (68) e (69); all’infinito presente, come in (70), (71) e (72):

**(62) mi domando che cosa ho fatto di male**

(63) spiegami chi è il tuo amico

(64) ditemi se verrete a cena

(65) nessuno sa dove sia

(66) ignoro che cosa stia combinando

(67) non so se verrebbe volentieri

**(68) mi chiedo che cosa avresti fatto se fossi stato al mio posto**..."

La tua domanda si puo riscrivere come "Mi domando quale sia/è l'origine".

Comment: E in che senso “sono curiosa di sapere” è un “verbo di opinione e pensiero”?

Comment: @DaG Il verbo che regge la subordinata in questo caso è _sapere_ e non _sono curiosa_. Col che, la risposta continua a sembrarmi sbagliata perché ovviamente _sapere_ non regge obbligatoriamente il congiuntivo (Mica si dice _So che sia stato tu!_).

Comment: @egreg hai ragione. Ho corretto la risposta

Comment: @MauroVanetti: Grazie per aver riscritto esplicitamente quello che pensavo bastasse dire in modo più implicito come avevo fatto io. Ma in effetti è sempre meglio qualche parola in più.

Answer (score 2):

Sono giuste entrambe e a rigore hanno lo stesso significato, ma in qualche modo usare il congiuntivo fa sembrare la domanda più "dubbiosa".

**EDIT:** Altre due risposte, che dicono che uno dei due modi sarebbe fortemente preferibile all'altro, una dando per obbligatorio il congiuntivo, l'altra dicendo praticamente l'opposto, mi hanno fatto riflettere. Sono convinto che sia possibile usare entrambe le forme, come di fatto avviene nella lingua sia parlata sia scritta, ma vorrei provare a spiegare come mai.

I verbi che esprimono dubbio, pensiero, opinione, reggono di norma il congiuntivo nella loro subordinata. Per esempio:

> Dubito che l'origine sia questa.
>   Penso che l'origine sia questa.
>   Credo che l'origine sia questa.

Il verbo *sapere*, invece, regge l'indicativo se si deve affermare una conoscenza che è posseduta dal soggetto della principale. Per esempio:

> So che l'origine è questa.

Eppure, ed è qua l'inghippo, se si usa *sapere* per dire che **non** si possiede una certa conoscenza, le due regole entrano in conflitto. Naturalmente si può ancora dire:

> Non so se l'origine è questa.

Però, in fondo, questa frase non assomiglia un bel po', come significato, a quella sopra che inizia con *Dubito*? E allora ecco qua:

> Non so se l'origine sia questa.

Molto meglio. Il verbo *sapere* usato per dire che in realtà qualcuno **non** sa qualcosa, regge pure, e oserei dire preferibilmente, il congiuntivo, come i verbi che esprimono pensiero, opinione, dubbio. Lo stesso vale per *ignorare*, *domandare* ecc.

Nell'esempio in questione, il soggetto è curioso di sapere qualcosa, dunque non lo sa. La frase resta sospesa tra *sapere qual è l'origine* e *non sapere quale sia l'origine* e quindi entrambe le forme sono valide, con una leggerissima sfumatura di mistero o dubbio in più nella versione col congiuntivo.

Comment: La correzione di un'altra risposta spiega la cosa in termini più scientifici di questo mio volo pindarico. :-) Vanno bene tutte e due.

Answer (score 2):

Vado controcorrente e ti dico che è giusto l'indicativo. Prova a sostituire *sono curiosa* con *mi piacerebbe* e sentirai che

> mi piacerebbe sapere quale sia l'origine

stride, mentre

> mi piacerebbe sapere qual è l'origine

scivola liscia. Almeno al mio orecchio. Dunque

> sono curiosa di sapere qual è l'origine

va benissimo.

È un'interrogativa indiretta subordinata a un verbo che esprime volontà, desiderio; non c'è alcun “dubbio“ implicito o esplicito.

Se poi vuoi metterci il congiuntivo, nessuna obiezione, naturalmente. Un punto di partenza può essere la [voce nell'enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/interrogative-indirette_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29%2F).

Comment: "Sono curiosa di sapere"... piu dubbio di cosi?

Comment: @algiogia Non ci vedo alcun dubbio.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sarei curioso di sapere quale sia il suo nome (meno diretto = molto formale)
2. Sarei curioso di sapere quale sia il tuo nome
3. Sono curioso di sapere qual è il suo nome
4. Sono curioso di sapere qual è il tuo nome
5. Quel è il tuo nome? (molto diretto = più informale)

Nelle risposte precedenti è stata presa in considerazione solo la "sfumatura del dubbio" del congiuntivo, ma questo esprime anche una maggior formalità rispetto all'indicativo, proprio perché meno diretto ("Le andrebbe di..." > "Ti va di...").
Quindi secondo me questa è una zona grigia, in cui la scelta del congiuntivo propende per restare più sul dubbio e sul formale.