# Dubbio sull'uso del congiuntivo

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

Mi è stato detto che dire: Vorrei sapere se si "sappia"... è sbagliato, ma Treccani afferma che si possa usare sia il congiuntivo che l'indicativo: Vorrei sapere se si "sa".

Detto ciò, lo stesso discorso vale dopo una negazione: Nessuno di essi "sembra" funzionare vs Nessuno di essi sembri funzionare

Potete farmi un po' di chiarezza in merito?

Grazie

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Domande correlate: https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11021/, https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11020/, https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3866/, https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/10543/ (credo possa esserti utile dare un'occhiata alle loro risposte).

Answer (score 1):

I due esempi sono molto diversi.

Il secondo è più semplice, e la differenza non è nella negazione, ma nel fatto che si tratta di una proposizione principale: “Nessuno sembra” va sicuramente all'indicativo. Dire “Nessuno sembri” è un po' come dire “Io vada a casa”. L'unico caso in cui si potrebbe usare il congiuntivo in una frase simile è se in realtà si sta esprimendo un ordine: “Nessuno esca di qui!”

Per quanto riguarda la prima frase, si tratta di una principale da cui dipende un'interrogativa indiretta. (L'interrogativa diretta sarebbe “Si sa la cosa X?”, mentre un esempio di costruzione indiretta è appunto “Vorrei sapere se si sa/sappia la cosa X”).
Nell'italiano moderno, nelle interrogative indirette i due possibili modi, indicativo e congiuntivo sono ammessi entrambi e “non corrispondono in genere a un diverso grado di certezza ma, semmai, a un livello stilistico più o meno formale o a semplici variazioni libere” (Serianni, *Italiano*, XIV.86). Un esempio di alternanza viene da Corrado Alvaro:

> gli chiedeva quanti *erano* in casa, se *avesse* il padre e la madre, se *era* fidanzata.

A volte il congiuntivo esprime comunque una maggior incertezza o soggettività; lo si preferisce inoltre, ma non è obbligatorio, quando la principale è negativa. Un esempio citato dal Serianni:

> in primavera crescevano ... molte rose: e come mai *crescessero* non so, dato che nessuno di noi si sognava mai di annaffiarle (Ginzburg, *Lessico famigliare*).

In definitiva, nella frase proposta, a me personalmente il congiuntivo suona eccessivamente formale. Io probabilmente userei l'indicativo, magari riformulando la frase per evitare la sequenza “se si sa”.